# Ubuntu libexiv2.so.26 missing error message

Tags: exiv2

I am working with the exiv2 library. I currently faced an issue, and i can't find my way out of it. Here is the issue. 
I installed the exiv2 library. When I try to run it, the following error is given.

```
exiv2: error while loading the shared libraries: libexiv2.so.26: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But, when i open the /usr/local/lib folder, it exists there. Again when I try to locate the library using the ldd command, the command cannot locate it! 
Can anyone help me to find what is going on there? Thanks in advance! 
If not how to uninstall the whole library and reinstall it?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when using the sources for installing. 
You can remove the built files with `sudo make uninstall` from inside the sources folder of exiv2.

The solution to my problem was to simply use the package from the Ubuntu repository: `sudo apt install exiv2 libexiv2-dev`.

Hopefully this will help you too.